# python close file automatically like context manager

Tags: python

How to close this file or does the file automatically gets closed like a context manager `with`

```
lines = open(file_name).readlines()
```

I wanted to avoid the `with` statement as the above statement is a one liner, but now i see that the above said statement is of no use since we cannot close the file.

```
 with open(file_name)  as f:
          .....
```

Comment: The file will be closed at the end of the execution (at termination). To close the file manually: `f = open(file_name); lines = f.readlines(); f.close()`

Comment: The answer is given in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#open).

Comment: If you use the context manager form it will be more explicit when the file is closed.

Answer (score 2):

if you tend to use `open(filename)` in your expressions, rather than the `with` statement, wrap the with statement in your own function, and use it in the expression.

```
def open_readlines_and_close(filename, *args, **kwargs):
    with open(filename, *args, **kwargs) as file:
         lines = file.readlines()
    return lines

lines = open_readlines_and_close(file_name)
# apologies for the weird function name
```

you can also use generators to reduce the memory footprint if you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

```
lines = (lambda f=open(file_name): [f.readlines(), f.close()][0])()
```

However this would not be considered very Pythonic because it's not very readable.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `with`

This has the advantage that the file is properly closed after its suite finishes, even if an exception is raised on the way.

```
with open(file_name, 'r') as readfile:
    lines = readfile.readlines()
```